# image src change on mouse over in jquery

Tags: jquery, onmouseover

html-

```
<img id="storyimg" src="images/stor.jpg" alt="img" />  
                <ul class="sb_menu">            
                    <li><a href="linkpage.htm" class="newslink1">Wireless Networking at Fortune Inn, Noida</a></li>
                    <li><a href="linkpage.htm" class="newslink2">18th International Conference on Oral & Maxillofacial Surgery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="linkpage.htm" class="newslink3">WiFi deployment at Vellore Institute of Technology</a></li>                        
                </ul>
```

I want when user moves over these `li` items I want to change the image like-

```
<script>
                $('a.newslink1').bind('mouseover', function() {
                $('img#storyimg').src("images/stor1.jpg");
...same for newslink2 and 3, image will be stor2 and 3
```

**but this is not working i think i have written wrong jquery?????????**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `attr`:

```
$('img#storyimg').attr("src", "images/stor1.jpg");
```

**More Info:**

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 4):

**Your code:**

```
<script>
  $('a.newslink1').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $('img#storyimg').src("images/stor1.jpg");
```

**Errors:**

Line 3: use 'attr' instead  of 'src' like '.attr("src","images/stor1.jpg");'

Line 4: ' }); ' is missing at end of the statment

**Correct code:**

```
<script>
  $('a.newslink1').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $('img#storyimg').attr("src","images/stor1.jpg");
  });
```

If you want to change the image depend on the link you can code:

```
<img id="storyimg" src="images/stor.jpg" alt="img" />  
<ul class="sb_menu">            
  <li><a href="linkpage.htm" class="newslink1" data-image="stor1.jpg">Wireless Networking at Fortune Inn, Noida</a></li>
  <li><a href="linkpage.htm" class="newslink2" data-image="stor2.jpg">18th International Conference on Oral & Maxillofacial Surgery</a></li>
  <li><a href="linkpage.htm" class="newslink3" data-image="stor3.jpg">WiFi deployment at Vellore Institute of Technology</a></li>                        
</ul>

<script>
  //binds the mouseover-event-handler to all Links the are childs of an LI in UL with Class "sb_menu"
  $('UL.sb_menu LI A').bind('mouseover', function(e) { 
    $('img#storyimg').attr("src","images/" + $(e.target).attr('data-image'));
  });
</script>
```

An improve: "img#storyimg" as selector is ok but only "#storyimg" is mutch faster because getElementById(..) is an native-browser-function. If you use "img#storyimg" jquery must request getElementsByTagName('IMG') and traverse the list to find this element with the id "storyimg". this takes a lot of time equals to the direct execution of "getElementById".
An ID of any HTML-Element in a page must be unice. see: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2 ("This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.")

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a.newslink1').bind('mouseover', function() {
$('img#storyimg').attr("src","images/stor1.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `$('img#storyimg').attr('src','path/to/new/image.jpg');`

EDIT: JINX gotta but me a coke! :o)

one more thing, experiment with `.mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()`.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's long ago that the question was asked, but maybe someone could need some other solutions. So I thought, maybe I could help too.

You could also use the ".hover()" function, maybe like this:

This one between `<head>` and `</head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var src_path = "path/images/";
        var src_suffix = ".jpg";                   
        $('.yourclass').hover(                         
            function () {
            $(this).addClass("hover");
            var active_id = $(this).attr('id');     
            $('#' + active_id + '_pic').attr("src", src_path + active_id + '_big' + src_suffix); 
            },
            function () {
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
            var active_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#' + active_id + '_pic').attr("src", src_path + active_id + '_small' + src_suffix);
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

And this one between `<body>` and `</body>`:

```
<div class="fruits">
<a href="#" class="yourclass" id="apple">
<img id="apple_pic" src="files/images/apple_small.jpg" alt="apple" title="apple" />
</a>
<!--  -->
<a href="#" class="yourclass" id="pear">
<img id="pear_pic" src="files/images/pear_small.jpg" alt="pear" title="pear" />
</a>
</div>
```

On one of our websites, it works well.

More Information about the ".hover()" function, you could find here: http://api.jquery.com/hover/